# Pyro4 connect with java

Tags: java, python, rmi

Hi all I have question related with Pyro4 and Java. My question is how can I send information between RMI server in Java and clients RMI in Python?.
This is my code, I don't have any errors but I can't send anything.

**Java Code:**

```
implements ReceiveMessageInterface
{
    int      thisPort;
    String   thisAddress;
    Registry registry;    // rmi registry for lookup the remote objects.

    // This method is called from the remote client by the RMI.
    // This is the implementation of the �gReceiveMessageInterface�h.
    public void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public RmiServer() throws RemoteException
    {
        try{
            // get the address of this host.
            thisAddress= (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RemoteException("can't get inet address.");
        }

        thisPort=3232;  // this port(registry�fs port)
        System.out.println("this address="+thisAddress+",port="+thisPort);
        try{
        // create the registry and bind the name and object.
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( thisPort );
            registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        }
        catch(RemoteException e){
        throw e;
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
        RmiServer s=new RmiServer();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.exit(1);
    }
     }
}
```

And this is my code in Python:

> import Pyro4
>
> proxy=Pyro4.core.Proxy("PYRONAME:PhDJara/127.0.1.1")
>
> print("5*11=%d" % proxy.multiply(5,11)) print("'x'*10=%s" %
>   proxy.multiply('x',10))

Thanks for your help.

jarain78

Comment: There's something missing at the beginning of the Java class. I don't see the point of the `thIsAddress` field. RMI servers don't need to know their own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that you should be able to connect these two? 
Pyro4 is only conceptually similar to Java's RMI, but they're two totally different protocols. You cannot connect them directly.

If you want to write a Python client using Pyro and talk to a server, that server has to be a Pyro server. The only way to create one in Java is by using Jython + Pyro.